# Trouble with watir install

Tags: ruby, windows, nokogiri, watir

I have been having trouble trying to get Watir to work on my Windows 7 x64 machine.  I am using the following:

http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p448.exe
https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe

I first install the ruby.exe listed above, and that seemed to go fine when installed to c:\ruby193.  I then extracted the dev kit listed above, to c:\devkit.  I then switched to c:\rubydev and ran `ruby dk.rb init` and opened the config.yml file to make sure it was correct, it was.  I then ran `ruby dk.rb install` and that seemed to go fine, and got the following as a result:

```
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby193'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'
```

The problem comes when I try to install watir.  I typed `gem install watir` and got the following:

```
C:\Ruby193>gem install watir
Fetching: commonwatir-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: multi_json-1.7.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: rubyzip-0.9.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: ffi-1.9.0-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Fetching: childprocess-0.3.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: websocket-1.0.7.gem (100%)
Fetching: selenium-webdriver-2.35.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: watir-webdriver-0.6.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: win32-process-0.7.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: win32-api-1.4.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Fetching: windows-api-0.4.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: windows-pr-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: mini_portile-0.5.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.0.rc1.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing watir:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --with-iconv-dir
        --without-iconv-dir
        --with-iconv-include
        --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
        --with-iconv-lib
        --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
        --with-xml2-dir
        --without-xml2-dir
        --with-xml2-include
        --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
        --with-xml2-lib
        --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
        --with-xslt-dir
        --without-xslt-dir
        --with-xslt-include
        --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
        --with-xslt-lib
        --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
        --with-libxslt-config
        --without-libxslt-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libxml-2.0-config
        --without-libxml-2.0-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libiconv-config
        --without-libiconv-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0.rc1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0.rc1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

I am not sure what to do from here, I have tried to clean the directories and do the process again but can't seem to get past this.

My ultimate goal is to get Watir installed so I can do automated testing in IE.

Comment: The problem is actually with installing "Nokogiri" rather than with installing "Watir".

Comment: OK, I seem to have answered my own issue.  I found another post mentioning an older version of a gem to install:

gem install nokogiri -v "1.5.9"

Once I did that I re-installed the watir gem and I was able to then control IE through IRB.  

Here is the other post I found:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933872/gem-install-watir-not-working

Comment: You can vote my answer up in that thread to make it more noticeable.